# Is there a way to do ParallelMapIndexed?

Tags: parallelization, core-language, map

I need the know the index of the items I'm mapping my function at, is there a way to achieve this when using all the kernels?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `MapIndex` in `Parallelize`? I tried something simple like `Parallelize[MapIndexed[#1 First@#2 &, CharacterRange["a", "z"]]]` and it worked without complaints, but I don't know whether the operation was effectively parallelized. Perhaps if we had a better idea of your function and data...

Comment: @MarcoB It works just fine in 10.1.0 under Windows.  You can use `$KernelID` to check parallel operation: `Parallelize[MapIndexed[{$KernelID, ##} &, CharacterRange["a", "z"]]]`.  M.R. does this fail for you?  If so we need details; if not this is probably "easily found in the documentation."